# can I use 2 different classes for the same icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i ran into this css problem, i'm using react and i implemented in one page 2 icons (whatsapp and facebook) and in another page the same thing. I am using the fontawsome classes, the problem is that if I change the aspect ratio, I also automatically change the icon of the other page.

First page:(js)

```
              <Btnwts buttonSize='btn3--wide' buttonColor='green'>
              <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> <a href="https://wa.me/">{buttonLabel2}</a>
              </Btnwts>

              <Btnmsn buttonSize='btn4--wide' buttonColor='primary'>
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i> <a href="https://m.me                       
              /">{buttonLabel3}</a>
              </Btnmsn>
```

Second page(js+css):

```
              <Link to={'//wa.me/'} target='_blank'>
              <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
              </Link>

              <Link to={'//m.me/'} target='_blank'>
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i>
              </Link>
```

css:

```
.fa-whatsapp{
font-size: 3rem;
position: relative;
margin-left: 20px;
top: 8px;
color: rgb(26, 212, 26);
animation: verde 1s linear infinite ;
}

.fa-facebook-messenger{
font-size: 2.8rem;
position: relative;
margin-left: 20px;
top: 8px;
color: rgb(26, 107, 212);
animation: verde 1s linear infinite ;
}
```

so my question is, how do i change the name of the icon classes since if i try to change them it won't recognize the icon, thanks!

Comment: The `C` in `CSS` is for «cascading», this is your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many classes as you want to any element. To customise one of the Font Awesome icons, you can simply add another class after the existing classes - each class is separated by a space, so the icons actually have **two** classes already - `.fab` and `.fa-facebook-messenger`.

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger my-class"></i>
```

Comment: Thank u so much!!

Answer (score 0):

you can put 3rd class name into the class of the element..
on css add the new class below of what you have and add your style (the last style will overwrote the style's above)